# accessing variable of structure through structure pointer assign wrong data

Tags: c++

```
/* c++ file */
extern "C"
{
#include "Param.h"
#include "manager.h"      
}
void Manager::Init(){

    struct config pParam;   
    memset(&pParam, 0, sizeof(pParam));

    pParam.pulse = 123;
    pParam.rotation = 567;

    Parameters(&pParam);
}

/* c file */
int max_pulse = 0, rotation = 0;
void Parameters(const struct config *p_param)
{
    max_pulse   = p_param->pulse; // assign the wrong data here
    rotation    = p_param->rotation; // assign the wrong data here
}
```

It is a very strange problem.

config is defined in Param.h and manager class is define in manager.h file.

After running the code, I am getting max-pulse = 567 and rotation = 0. 
I don't know why this is happening with this code. I am using visual studio 2008 express.

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Make your question self contained - what you post should copy paste compile.  Delete unrelated parts of code before posting.  And Init p_param is not declared in the code you posted.

Comment: Where and how max_pulse and rotation are defined? Are you using/modifying those between call to Parameters() and checking those values?

Comment: max_pulse and rotation are global variables. Both are not calling anywhere else and not modifying in between.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting errors probably because you are caliing `Parameters()` function with `pParam` argument whereas you are initializing `p_param` members.